# Oracle Apex 20.1 Cascading LOV not working correctly

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I am using apex 20.1 and try to implement the new cascading lovs option. However it is not working as per expectation.

Can you suggest where am I going wrong.

I have 2 items in my region:

- `:P5_ASSIGNED_DEPT` - Assigned department for each employee
- `:P5_PERSON_NAME` - Name of employee

I want the name of employees to populate as per assigned dept in table.
If `assigned_Dept` is FINANCE, only employees with assigned dept as finance should populate in `:P5_PERSON_NAME`.

I made these changes:

[image]
But despite selecting finance, i am getting names of all employess irrespective of dept.

What more changes are needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that query you used for `P5_PERSON_NAME` doesn't contain `P5_ASSIGNED_DEPT`. Apex can't *automagically* add `WHERE` clause to your query, you have to do it yourself.

So: `P5_PERSON_NAME`'s LoV query should look like this:

```
select e.ename as display_value,
       e.id    as return_value
from emp e
where e.dept_id = :P5_ASSIGNED_DEPT
```